# How to exit a Shiny app and return a value

Tags: r, shiny

The help page for `runApp` says:

> Runs a Shiny application. This function normally does not return;
>   interrupt R to stop the application (usually by pressing Ctrl+C or
>   Esc).

Does "normally" mean "always"?  Is there any way to add an "exit" button and return a value to the R session that called `runApp`?  Even if it's a hack, this would be convenient functionality.  I've tried some searching but haven't found anything.  I've also looked at the source for `runApp`, the last line is `return(.globals$retval)`, so it looks like there should be a way.

Can I set `.globals$retval` directly and then call some kind of interrupt?  Is there a function in the `shiny` package that does this?

Comment: There is a `stopApp` function that has this functionality see `?shiny::stopApp`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a `stopApp` function that stops the running app and returns an optional value:

```
myValue <- runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    actionButton("myBtn", "Press ME!"),
    plotOutput('plot')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$n)) });
    observe({
      if(input$myBtn > 0){
        stopApp(7)
    }
    })
  }
))
```

On stopping:

```
> myValue
[1] 7
```