# Disconnect from PostgreSQL when close R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, rpostgresql

This question is admittedly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365575/how-to-exit-a-shiny-app-and-return-a-value) but the answer provided is not sufficient for my example.

I am creating a Shiny App that connects to a database.  The user can provide some inputs and some 'canned' queries will run.  Now, I would like to make certain the connection to the database is closed on exit from the app.  I could use a button and the `stopApp` function but this assumes users will be good and always click said button.  Users are likely to sometimes close the window leaving the database connection open so I would like to find a way to explicitly close the connection when the user closes the app window.

I suppose one solution would be to instantiate a new connection and close at the end of each query but that seems inefficient.

Here is some working code to demonstrate the problem.  If I run this App from Rstudio and then close the window, I still have an existing connection as per `dbListConnections(PostgreSQL())`.  Appending `dbDisconnect(con)` to the end of the file does not help.

```
library(shiny)
library(RPostgreSQL)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  # Read in the dataset
  connectDB <- eventReactive(input$connectDB, {

    if(input$drv != "postgresql"){
      stop("Only 'postgresql' implemented currently")
    }else{
      drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
      port = 5432
    }

    con <- dbConnect(drv, user = input$user, password = input$passwd, 
                     port = port, host = input$server, dbname=input$db_name)
    con
  })

  output$test <- renderText({
    con <- connectDB()
    "connection success"
  })
})


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Test Connection"),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("drv", "Database Driver", value="postgresql"),
        textInput("user", "User ID"),
        textInput("server", "Server", value="server"),
        textInput("db_name", "Database Name", value="dbName"),
        passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
        actionButton("connectDB", "Connect to DB")
      ),

      mainPanel(
        textOutput("test")
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: perhaps use `session$onSessionEnded`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you know about the `onSessionEnded` of the `session` variable?

Here's a very basic example that sets a random session id to each user and when they close the window, a function runs that says what session id was closed.  It's just a proof of concept, you can tailor it to your database needs trivially I hope

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textOutput("sessionId")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    sessionId <- as.integer(runif(1, 1, 100000))
    output$sessionId <- renderText(paste0("Session id: ", sessionId))
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      cat(paste0("Ended: ", sessionId))
    })
  }
))
```

**Edit:**

Op said he needs the variable to be reactive, so here's a modification that I believe would allow him what he wants

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textOutput("sessionId")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues(sessionId = NULL)
    values$sessionId <- as.integer(runif(1, 1, 100000))
    output$sessionId <- renderText(paste0("Session id: ", values$sessionId))
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      observe(cat(paste0("Ended: ", values$sessionId)))
    })
  }
))
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if putting the observe inside the onSessionEnded callback is the best approach. This works, but I can't vouch for it's "correctness".

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the `onSessionEnded` variable.  Should have thought to look at the session object documentation.  To completely solve my problem I needed to create a global variable to refer to the existing connection but this allowed me to do it.

Comment: If you only have one user connected at a time that's fine.  If you're allowing multiple users to connect, then when the first user leaves, I think that would cause all connections to die since all sessions are sharing the same global connection

Comment: a valid point, did you have another idea how to get the reactive connection object?

Comment: Would just moving the `con` object inside of the `shinyServer` be sufficient?

Comment: Why not just use `on.exit()`?

Comment: @hadley where would the `on.exit()` go? If it's inside the server function, it'll just be called after the app initializes. Would you write a wrapper around `shinyApp()` and add it there?

Comment: Good point - I thought the function was long running, but indeed it terminates quickly.