# Call R Shiny App with Argument

Tags: r, shiny

Update, I tried writing app using object (explained [here](https://github.com/jcheng5/seattle-meetup/blob/master/diamonds2/explore.R)), but I get same error

Updated internal app function

```
CustomPalette <- function(new_pal=NULL){
  if (interactive()){
    colorfile <- paste(getwd(),"colorfile.txt",sep="/")
    if (!file.exists(colorfile)){
      file.create(colorfile)
    }
    app <- list(
      ui = fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Cherry Pick Your Own Palette!"),
        sidebarPanel (hr(),
                      selectInput('col', 'Options', new_pal, multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE, size = 15)
        ),
        mainPanel(
          h5('Your custom colors',style = "font-weight: bold;"),
          fluidRow(column(12,verbatimTextOutput("col"))))
      ),
      server = function(input,output,session){
        outputdata<-  reactive({
          input$col
        })

        output$col <- { 
          renderPrint(outputdata())
        }
        session$onSessionEnded(function(){
          message <- paste(isolate(outputdata())," ")
          cat(message,file=colorfile, append=TRUE)
          customcolors <- scan(file=colorfile," ")
          stopApp(customcolors)
          customcolors
        })
      }
    )
  }

}
```

---

I am attempting to call R Shiny App with an argument, i.e. `customcolors <- runApp(CustomPalette(new_pal = NULL))`

This launches shiny app, allowing user to select individual colors, which the app returns as a vector

Unfortunately, `devtools::check()` gives error for [entire R script](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R)

```
> CherryPickPalette("GoldenTemple","AmritsariPedeWaliLassi")
Error in UseMethod("as.shiny.appobj", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'as.shiny.appobj' applied to an object of class "NULL"
Calls: CherryPickPalette -> runApp -> as.shiny.appobj
Execution halted
```

Below is `CherryPickPalette` function, which invokes `CustomPalette` function that contains shiny app (also included).

Ultimately, the user should be able to execute `CherryPickPalette(name, name2, name3)`, shiny app should appear, user should pick whatever colors they want, and variable should be saved and used within entire script.

```
# visible to user
CherryPickPalette <- function (name, name2=NULL, name3=NULL){

  ### snipped code

  customcolors <- runApp(CustomPalette(new_pal = NULL))

  customcolors

}

# hidden from user
CustomPalette <- function(new_pal){
  if (interactive()){
    colorfile <- paste(getwd(),"colorfile.txt",sep="/")
    if (!file.exists(colorfile)){
      file.create(colorfile)
    }
    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Cherry Pick Your Own Palette!"),
        sidebarPanel (hr(),
                      selectInput('col', 'Options', new_pal, multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE, size = 15)
        ),
        mainPanel(
          h5('Your custom colors',style = "font-weight: bold;"),
          fluidRow(column(12,verbatimTextOutput("col"))))
      ),
      server = function(input,output,session){
        outputdata<-  reactive({
          input$col
        })

        output$col <- { 
          renderPrint(outputdata())
        }
        session$onSessionEnded(function(){
          message <- paste(isolate(outputdata())," ")
          cat(message,file=colorfile, append=TRUE)
          customcolors <- scan(file=colorfile," ")
          stopApp(customcolors)
          customcolors
        })
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/440. You either need to use global variables as described in the issue or use `options`

Comment: ok, then I will either go the globalvariables route or tinker with options .....